# Screen Dimming Anomaly

Tags: 14.04, power-management, screen, brightness, battery

My Lenovo G780 with Ubuntu 14.04 is fine when the AC charger is plugged in. However, when unplugged, if my mouse does not move for ~12 seconds, the screen dims a bit, but this is not detected by my brightness settings changing. This is very annoying as I can still be sitting at a computer doing something, just not moving the mouse in 12 seconds, so the screen dims. And I end up using the computer and constantly having the screen flicker sometimes and adjusting it.

Currently, I have browsed almost every askubuntu thread about this.

Dconf Editor: org>gnome>settings-daemon>plugins>power : idle dim is unchecked, sleep-inactive-timeout for battery and ac is 1200 seconds each

Caffeine: currently on, no effect

Brightness and Lock: Dim screen to save power is unchecked

Nothing I have done since installing ubuntu has changed anything about this. All I would want is to make the dimming happen after a more reasonable time of 60 seconds or so. Power and Brightness&Lock settings have no further options to affect this. I've also tried some command line advice like turning off dpms (energy saver) and things like that.

I would also add that my laptop does have screen brightness adjusting Fn keys as I've heard this can make a difference.Any help is greatly appreciated!